# Google recaptcha validation in yii2 always fails

Tags: yii2

I use `himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget`. I always get a validation error when I submit the form.

```
{"captcha":["The verification code is incorrect."]}.
```

Form:

```
$form->field($model, 'captcha',['template' => "{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"])->widget(
            \himiklab\yii2\recaptcha\ReCaptcha::className(),
            [
            'siteKey' => <mysitekey>,
            'widgetOptions' => ['id'=>'recaptcha1']
            ])
```

Controller:

```
if(isset($_POST['Contact'])){
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about trying that basic Captcha which is given in template?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Yii always run validation twice, on validation() method and during the save executes again the validation, this cause that the first validation is successful however the second returns an error.
So, for the second case you will need to save without running the validations, which save(false).

The second chance might be to unhook the validation of the captcha just before the safe() method.

Comment: The problem is somewhere else. I'm having the same problem and even if I disable validation on save, it won't work.